# Add reference of a .NET library residing in Windows System32 folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, system32

I am using a .NET dll file for image operations and have added it in my C# application using "Add reference" in solution explorer and use its classes. There are many applications use that dll so I do not want to place the dll file in an application specific folder like:

- `C:\Program Files\<Application Name>\` or
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\<Application Name>\` or
- `C:\ProgramData\<Application Name>\` or
- `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\`

And would like to place the dll file in a common folder like `C:\Windows\` or `C:\Windows\System32` folder or any other folder that is commonly accessible by all applications in Windows.

It works fine when I put the the dll file in the same folder of the calling exe, but when I place it in `C:\Windows\System32` directory, the C# code of my application is not able to locate the dll and gives error:

> Unable to load DLL: The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

How do I instruct my code to look for the dll in the system32 directory or in any other common directory?

What other common folder can I use for shared dll and libraries?

Comment: Don't do that. Use `Program Files\Common Files\<Your Subdirectory>` instead.

Comment: Read up on [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dll_hell) to find out why the thing you're asking for is a *terrible* idea.

Comment: @JoeWhite Ok. The problem is that the dll is already placed in System32 directory most of the time, and code will use that dll if it is already found there during installation. But I do not know how to access a Windows/system32 dll in C# code.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Ok. The problem is that the dll is already placed in System32 directory most of the time, and code will use that dll if it is already found there during installation. But I do not know how to access a Windows/system32 dll in C# code.

Comment: "already placed in System32" Who places the DLL in System32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the Global Assembly Cache is designed for. As listed in the MS documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Each computer where the common language run-time is installed has a
>   machine-wide code cache called the global assembly cache. The global
>   assembly cache stores assemblies specifically designated to be shared
>   by several applications on the computer.

But there are pitfalls to using it so be aware of MS's own advice:

> You should share assemblies by installing them into the global
>   assembly cache only when you need to. As a general guideline, keep
>   assembly dependencies private, and locate assemblies in the
>   application directory unless sharing an assembly is explicitly
>   required.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share a link or tutorial of a sample code on how to use GAC in C#/Visual Studio?